# PHP DOM GET HREF ATTRIBUTE BETWEEN TABLE

Tags: php, dom, html-table, attributes, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get multiple href's from a table like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="text-center">No</th>
         <th>TITLE</th>
         <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
         <th class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr data-key="11e44c4ebff985d08ca5313231363233">
       <td class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">181</td>
       <td style="width:auto; white-space: normal;"><a href="link-1.html">Link 1</a></td>
       <td style="width:auto; white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor 1</td>
       <td class="text-center" style="width: 50px;"><a href="link-1.pdf" title="Download" target="_blank"><img src="https://example.com/img/pdf.png" width="15" height="20" alt="myImage"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="11e44c4e4222d630bdd2313231323532">
       <td class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">180</td>
       <td style="width:auto; white-space: normal;"><a href="link-2.html">Link 2</a></td>
       <td style="width:auto; white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor 2</td>
       <td class="text-center" style="width: 50px;"><a href="link-2.pdf" title="Download" target="_blank"><img src="https://example.com/img/pdf.png" width="15" height="20" alt="myImage"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i try PHP DOM like this

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('data2.html');
 
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument;
$htmlDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$htmlDom->loadHTML($html);
$tables = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

foreach ($rows as $row) 
  { 
      $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
      echo @$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
      echo @$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
      echo trim($cols->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')).'<br />';
      echo @$cols->item(2)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
      echo trim($cols->item(3)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')).'<br />';
   } 
?>
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null

getAttribute causes the error

Could someone help me out here please thanks

Comment: It's obvious that something (`$tables->item(0)` or `$cols->item(1)` or `$cols->item(3)`) is __null__. `var_dump` and check.

Comment: Because the first `tr` doesn't contain any `td` tags (in the `thead`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: nodeValue is fine but cannot getAttribute for href

Comment: would be helpfull, if you can say, which getElementsByTagName causes the error

Comment: The error is not about `getAttribute`. The error you get is because there are no elements in `$cols` in the first line of the loop body. Which happens, because the first `tr` you iterate on does not contain any `td` tags. To fix the problem, change `table` to `tbody` here: `$htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('table');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$rows` are results of "all the `<tr>` within `<table>`". It not only caught the `<tr>` in the table body, it also caught that in your table head, which has no `<td>` in it. Hence when reading that row, `$cols->item(0)` and `$cols->item(1)` both got you `NULL`.

You should take the hint when your code didn't find `->nodeValue` attribute in the items (hence you added the `@` sign to suppress the warning).

Try to change this:

```php
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

into this:

```php
$rows = $tables
        ->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tbody')
        ->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Now it is searching the `<tr>` within your `<tbody>` and should fix your issue with this particular HTML.

To have a more robust code, you should have checked the variables before acting on them. A type check or count check would be good.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous access to the `$cols` array all have `@` to suppress the errors, this is the first one that complains.

A simple fix would be to just skip the rest of the code if no `<td>` elements are found (such as the header row)...

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    if ( count($cols) == 0 )    {
        continue;
    }
```

You could alternatively use XPath and only select `<tr>` tags which contain `<td>` tags.